# SQL Server 2014 Memory Optimized Table with Entity Framework 6.1 CodeFirst

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My application uses two lookup tables I want to be Memory Optimized Tables.

There seems to be no Attribute yet to declare this;

Is there a possibility to hook into the table creation process and look for an custom attribute and modify the create table command?

I use Entity Framework 6.1 with Code First.

**I seek a way to make it declarative, so if e.g. EF 6.2 or newer version supports it official, i can drop my hack.**

Comment: I doubt you can have two in-memory tables and have other tables in sql and expect that EF will be able to work on two different data sources.

Comment: it is a sql server 2014 feature. the datasource is the same.

Comment: Ok, I know this feature as Memory-Optimized tables rather than In-Memory tables and I thought you are going to implement a custom solution.

Comment: Not with code-first, that's sure.

Comment: I know not by default, i look for an hack or an extension to make it possible :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd replace the CreateTable with the specific sql you want to optimise your database, called in the Up migration using Sql("create table etc..").

This is restricted to Sql Server 2014 and further restricted by other requirements for memory optimisation. Not worth the candle trying to do it with attributes within EF.

Comment: i go this way as it was also recommended by an EF team member

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create an Entity Framework DB initializer that drop and recreate the table?

Something like (pseudo code!):

```
    public class MyDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DROP TABLE MyTable");
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE MyTable (bla bla bla)  WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON)");
        }
    }
```

I can't test this feature because I don't have SQL 2014 but I have used the `Seed` method to alter my database in many situations so it should work.

You can then assign your database initializer using:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyDbInitializer());
```

Comment: Thaught about something like this, but how do i map it to an attribute? I seek a way to make it declarative, so if e.g. EF 6.2 or whatever which version supports it official, i can drop my hack. +1

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but FYI memory-optimized tables have first-class support in the upcoming Entity Framework Core 1.1 (preview1 has just been released).